# MS Access VBA: how to trap case where delete hangs due to low memory or disk space?

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, low-memory

I have a sporadic error in MS Access 2007 which I can't reliably reproduce. The circumstances are these:

1. Load 500K+ rows of text data from file into a table
2. [do stuff with loaded data]
3. Attempt to delete contents of table from vba with
   **CurrentDB().Execute "Delete * from RawImport"**, where RawImport is the table name

At step 3, the code will sometimes hang up until I ctrl-Break. When this happens, if Ctrl-F11 back to the database view and attempt to delete the contents of the table, it will always give me an error  "*there is not enough memory or disk space to complete this action with undo, do you want to continue*" (paraphrased, I haven't been able to capture the error)

Exiting Access and reloading will usually clear this so that the VBA code runs, which is all fine and lovely, but how can I trap for this? It doesn't generate an error in the vba at the delete, it just sits there at the line until I break manually.

Comment: I think this is too much data for msAccess, you are risking corrupting the database. If it is possible you should use MSSQL instead. I am also looking forward for someone's answer

Comment: Watch the size of the Access DB during your processing and see how large the file grows during processing. I am guessing you are running into the 2GB size limit

Comment: " complete this action with undo" --- so you do want to continue but you don't provide any input in order to do so. Try seeing if there is another way to delete the table with input to 'ignore undo' or if there's another method like runsql

Comment: Is it an option to drop the table, and rebuild as empty?

Comment: Hynek is incorrect. 500k rows is NOT too much for Access. As suggested, check the file size. Can you post relevant code? You may have fewer problems is you declare a database variable, rather than using CurrentDb(). Dim dbS as dao.Database Set dbS = CurrentDb() sbS.Execute <yoursql>, dbFailOnError. The UI warning only has to do with the UI. It's just telling you that once you delete the records, you can't undo it.

Comment: It isn't to much, dropping the table and re-creating it would be a good route forward if possible, if not, consider maybe using a loop to delete 10000 at a time. Also consider running 'CompactRepair' as a house keeping move.

Comment: Hynek Bernard / random_answer_guy. The database was nowhere near max size at the time - less than 1GB. I have worked with much larger tables & databases before without this issue

AVG The code is pretty much as you suggest.         
       Set db = currentDB()
       db.Execute "Delete * from RawImport"
I abbreviated in my original post

@Gary Evans. Good lateral thinking. I think that this, combined with forcing a periodic compress of the database is probably the way to go - subsequent testing has shown that repeated load/delete/.. cycles causes the db to inflate to the 2GB limit

Comment: Keep in mind dropping and adding the table back in will push you closer to the limit much faster. Remember, the objects are `marked for deletion` but are not actually deleted until a compact and repair

Comment: @random_answer_guy You're right, I have found the same thing in testing. I think my next approach is to create an additional database on the fly to hold the data and drop the whole database rather than the table. It is a very annoying and restricting limitation though  - the garbage collection in Access is not very effective

Comment: In the end, I did follow the approach of creating a temporary database, creating the table on the fly in that one, linking it from my main database and then deleting the temporary database at the of each load/process cycle. 

It works OK, but it's a bit over-complicated for a really simple use-case of the database - not hard to see why people outgrow Access so readily.

Comment: Have you tried creating a delete query in the IDE & running that? e.g. DoCmd.OpenQuery("MyDeleteQuery"). My SpideySense tells me that ready made queries will be better optimized than code equivatents.

Comment: @Absinthe - that could potentially work to solve the original problem, but ultimately it just leads to the database fragmentation/size expansion that I hit later with other solutions

Comment: Compact and repair is your friend ;) Seriously, It nails fragmentation/size expansion.

Comment: C&R is definitely _not_ my friend in this case - I would have needed to perform this many times within a processing loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did follow the approach of creating a temporary database, creating the table on the fly in that one, linking it from my main database and then deleting the temporary database at the of each load/process cycle. It works OK, but it's a bit over-complicated for a really simple use-case of the database - not hard to see why people outgrow Access so readily.